# Write script to loop file even though called file breaks

Tags: loops, python

I know that this is not the most pythonic approach but I have a python script which due to some external effects breaks every 5 to 10 minutes. Now, I want to write a python script which will loop this file (forever), but it should restart the python script when it breaks.

The error is:

```
 IOError: ('http error', 401, 'Unauthorized', <httplib.HTTPMessage instance at 0x108994878>)
```

So how would I program this?

Comment: "but it should restart the python script when it breaks"  By "breaks" do you mean "gets an exception"?  Or do you mean "has run for 5 to 10 min"?  What code do you have now?  Are you asking how to check elapsed time?

Comment: no code, no attempts = downvote

Comment: right now I get the following IOError: ('http error', 401, 'Unauthorized', <httplib.HTTPMessage instance at 0x108994878>)

Comment: wow I used to be rep 44 one question and 25% less :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Handle the exception.](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions)

Answer (score 0):

Write a wrapper script which starts your process. When it finishes, restart it.

Comment: (This is a very brief answer because you gave a very brief question!)